# How to lift up RecyclerView with BottomSheet on CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I try add bottomSheet with `BottomSheetBehavior`, but it overlays on `RecycleView`, when I expand and hide with code:

```
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.EXPAND)
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.HIDE).
```

If I am adding `layout_anchor` on `RecycleView` - nothing happens.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can anchor your recyclerview to bottomsheet and set its `anchor_gravity`. add following code in your recyclerview in xml.

```
app:layout_anchor="@+id/your_bottom_sheet"
app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
```

Comment: not working, working for others (FAB), but for RecyclerView not work(

Comment: this working, while recyclerView not fullscreen, but I want when RecyclerView full screen and bottom sheet lift part of recyclerView

Comment: I also have same requirment, but can't find anything, you find any solution for this ?